# GDAL on Databricks Cluster Runtime 12.2 LTS

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, gdal

I need gdal in my course work.

After reading this [post](https://www.databricks.com/notebooks/rasterframes-notebook.html), I used init script as follows to install gdal into runtime 12.2 LTS

```
dbutils.fs.put("/databricks/scripts/gdal_install.sh","""
#!/bin/bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y cmake gdal-bin libgdal-dev python3-gdal""",
True)
```

The init script ran and cluster could start properly but when i run import gdal in notebook, i get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'

I also tried installing gdal into the cluster via Maven repository, it does not work either.

May I know what I can do to get gdal installed properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below way to install `GDAL`.

Alter the code in your `init` script as below and restart the cluster.

```
dbutils.fs.put("/databricks/scripts/gdal_install.sh","""
#!/bin/bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libgdal-dev""",
True)
```

[image]

After, restarting check the header version as below.

```
%sh
gdal-config --version
```

[image]

And the same version of `gdal` should be installed via pip.

Here, I got **3.3.2**.

```
pip install GDAL==3.3.2
```

Output:

[image]

After pip install your import statements will work.

Comment: thank you! it works now. would you mind to share what the alteration did? I am not that familiar with the script.. thank you again

Comment: I have installed required headers from linux repository and installed the same version of gdal  from pypi.

Comment: do i need to pip install GDAL all the time or can i add GDAL into the cluster libraries?

Comment: Yes. Because you want to instal GDAL version whichever shows when you do
`gdal-config --version`.

Comment: thank you. just one thing i need to clarify, the init script sometimes run well but often times it fail "Failed to add 11 containers to the compute. Will attempt retry: false. Reason: Init script failure" and Script exit status is non zero. What can i do to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Open new thread with script details and error screenshots.

Comment: thanks. i have created a new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76882655/gdal-on-databricks-12-2-lts-ml-add-nodes-failed